# PHPMailer - sending multiple emails with template system

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, sendmail

I would like to send multiple emails with little template system. I try myself, but not everything goes well. I have this template

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>new email template</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 640px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">


  <div align="center">
   Hi, 
   <p> I would like to send at your email {email}</p>
   <p> a little hash sum {hash}</p>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my PHPmailer fragment (up is only configure for my mail account)

```
$mail->Subject = "Mail sending template";

$recipients = array(
   'mail1@mail.com' => 'gfsggsfg5t653rwtwrwtwrt',
   'mail2@mail.com' => '6536536536356363636536356',

);

foreach($recipients as $email => $hash) { 

    $mail->addAddress($email);

    $vars = array('{email}','{hash}');
    $values = array($email,$hash);

    $body = str_replace($vars,$values,$body);
    $mail->msgHTML($body);
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $email) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
        break;
    } else {
        echo "Send ok for: :" .$email . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $email) . ')<br />';

    }

    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();
}
```

When I try to send those email it send ok. I can receive emails, but all have these same data: from first "row" of $recipments (mail1@mail.com). From mail2@mail.com I can receive an email, ,but with {email} and {hash} from mail1@mail.com.

What's wrong?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake: you're loading your original template into `$body` somewhere before the loop, but inside the loop you're overwriting `$body` with the replacements done, so the next time around the loop, your placeholders are no longer there. This should work:

```
$mail->Subject = "Mail sending template";

$recipients = array(
   'mail1@mail.com' => 'gfsggsfg5t653rwtwrwtwrt',
   'mail2@mail.com' => '6536536536356363636536356',

);

foreach($recipients as $email => $hash) { 

    $mail->addAddress($email);

    $vars = array('{email}','{hash}');
    $values = array($email,$hash);

    $body2 = str_replace($vars,$values,$body);
    $mail->msgHTML($body2);
    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error (" . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $email) . ') ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '<br />';
        break;
    } else {
        echo "Send ok for: :" .$email . ' (' . str_replace("@", "&#64;", $email) . ')<br />';

    }

    $mail->clearAddresses();
    $mail->clearAttachments();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do exactly that what You type :) I must add file_get_contents function into loop :)

Comment: You don't need to. Read the template once before the loop and re-use it, as the code I posted does.